# Concatenate $i to end of a variable name

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make it so that each time I loops through, the SQL statement changes to reflect the value of I as well.
For example, if there are two rows, I want it to execute an SQL statement with the variables `product1`, `quantity1`, `unit1` and also for the variable `proudct2`,`quantity2`,`unit2`.

Unfortunately, all it does is evaluate the same sql statement twice. How do I go about fixing it?? Thanks

```
for ($i = 1;$i=$numrows; $i++) {
     $sql= "INSERT INTO orderItem(order_id,item_linenum,product_id,item_quantity,item_unitprice)
          VALUES(".$_REQUEST["orderNumber"]."$i,'".$_REQUEST["product".$i]."','".$_REQUEST['quantity'.$i]."'," .$_REQUEST['unit'.$i].")";
    print "*" . $sql. "*" . "<br/>";
    $result= mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("SQL error: " . mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: for one thing `$i=$numrows` should probably be `$i<numrows`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: could you provide those sql statement which you got twice?

Comment: *INSERT INTO orderItem(order_id,item_linenum,product_id,item_quantity,item_unitprice) VALUES (1102,2,'BC501','1',200)*
*INSERT INTO orderItem(order_id,item_linenum,product_id,item_quantity,item_unitprice) VALUES (1102,2,'BC501','1',200)*

Comment: what is that value of $numrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this,

```
for ($i = 1;$i <= $numrows; $i++) {
               ^
```